# Finding all continuous solutions to an integral

Tags: integration, analysis

[image]

I need help with both parts of this problem. Part (i) seems obvious, because the integrand $f(t)$ would become $F(t)$, which is obviously differentiable because its derivative is $f(t)$ by construction. I just don't know how to prove it.
For part (ii), I am not sure how to find all continuous solutions..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formalize your idea for the first part, note that if we define

$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$$
then $F$ is continuously differentiable (since $f = F'$ is continuous). Now $f$ is the sum of continuously differentiable functions.

To find solutions, differentiate, and notice that

$$f' = 5 + 2f$$

which is a first-order ODE that can be solved with any number of techniques.

Comment: thanks! I haven't really studied ODEs yet, so I think I need help solving that, even though it looks so simple..